# Extract JSONObject and iterate through HashMap field

Tags: json, kotlin, request

I am trying to iterate through a value (that is a hashMap) of a JSONObject.

First I get a server response that is a String.

Then I turn it into a String! like this:

```
val responseString = response.serverResponse
```

Then I turn it into a JSONObject like this:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(responseString.toString()).get("data")
```

I do the second step because I only want to keep the LinkedHashMap shown in the picture attached.
But the second step returns type "Any" and then I cant iterate through the LinkedHashMap

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONObject myjsonObject = new JSONObject();
Iterator keyvalues = jsonObject.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {String key = keyvalues.next();
if (myjsonObject.get(key) instanceof myjsonObject) {

```
}
```

}