# Extract fields from complicated server response

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, hashmap

I have a server response that has this format:

```
{"bankAccounts":[
                  {"id"     :"wfasfsd",
                   "balance":{"amount":90, "currency":"GBP"}
                  }
                ]
```

I cant find out how to parse through it efficiently
For a similar response with of simpler format this post helped me ([Extract JSONObject and iterate through HashMap field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702281/extract-jsonobject-and-iterate-through-hashmap-field))

The picture shows exactly how the server response looks like. I need to extract this into JSON and in the end, I need to  have a HashMap with keys `id, amount, currency`
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by - parse through efficiently? Note, that `bankAccounts` here is an array, so you can get multiple `id` fields

Comment: Any way I could get the fields would be great. Especially if it was possible to put them all in a HashMap, like with keys, id, amount, currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json-simple library to read and write json objects.

[Here](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/07/jsonsimple-tutorial-read-and-write-json-in-java.html) you can see how to use it.